# Conditionally highlighting future date based on initial date value

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel (and Spreadsheeting in general), and am trying to harness the power of conditional formatting to highlight dates occurring every two weeks after a set date.

I have a fixed date value, and its serial:

```
# first occurrence of year, highlight today and every two weeks after
date: 01/05/2018
serial: 43105
```

Now, in my spreadsheet- I have a matrix of serial values in grid format for each month (i.e. full year calendar view).

I have a formula to get the first Sunday for each month. So serials are as follows:

```
# jan
date: 01/01/2018
serial: 43101

# feb
date: 02/01/2018
serial: 43129
```

I have a conditional rule to highlight the first occurrence, but am not sure how to implement the logic for occurrences every 14 days after the initial and thereafter.

My pseudo-code

```
for (each day in year, day) {
    if (day == specialDate) {
        // highlight cell, and update initialDate to this 
        highlightCell()
        specialDate = day + 14;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use modulus (Excel `MOD` function).

E.g. something like:

```
= MOD(<input date>-<reference date>,14)=0
```

If you use a formula like this for your conditional formatting rule, it will apply the formatting rule only to a those dates that are exact integer multiples of 14 days away from the `<reference date>` in the formula above.